# Tomcat 6 configuration example for Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: tomcat, grails, ubuntu

I'm very new to Tomcat and I'm having some issues figuring out how to set it up.  I set it up on Ubuntu Linux and started reading and *trying* to follow the information given on the apache website here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/deployer-howto.html

Apparently I'm missing something.  I have a WAR named MyWebapp.war and it's in a directory /home/mywebapp.  In /etc/tomcat6/Catalina/localhost/MyWebapp.xml, I have the following line:

```
<Context path="/MyWebapp" docBase="/home/mywebapp" antiResourceLocking="false" />
```

Everything else is the default configuration that came with tomcat6 via the Ubuntu package.  When I restart Tomcat and try to go to http://localhost:8080/MyWebapp, I get a 404.  The WAR file isn't unpacked and nothing seems to be working.

I'm going to be deploying two Grails applications on this server with Tomcat.

Is there a more straight forward way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the most straightforward way to deploy a .war to Tomcat is to use the [Manager Webapp](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html).

All you need to do is follow the instructions linked above. Setup a user in the default memory realm `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/tomcat-users.xml`. Navigate to `http://myserver:8080/`, log in with that user, deploy your app point-and-click style. Very handy, especially when you're getting started with Tomcat.

It also means you can deploy a war from your desktop, without having to manually copy it to the server.

Without using the manager webapp, you should be able to copy your war to `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps` and it should be automatically deployed for you. You shouldn't **have** to manually configure a Context for your app unless your app needs something like connection pooling resources setting up.

Answer (score 2):

If you installed the packaged version, then the default webapp location is:

```
/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps
```

This location belongs to the `tomcat6` user (you can use a symlink to your war if you want).

BTW, I don't know if what you're trying to do is possible but the current context configuration won't work. You're basically telling Tomcat that `/home/mywebapp` is a webapp (which is not the case), Tomcat will not look for a `.war` in there.

Actually, my recommendation would be to [download a vanilla Tomcat archive](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi), to unzip it somewhere in your home directory (I use `~/opt`) to install it and.. that's all.

Then to start Tomcat, just run:

```
$ ~/opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.26/bin$ ./startup.sh
```

To deploy a war, just copy it to:

```
~/opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.26/webapp
```

Comment: I saw that and I put my war in that directory and restarted tomcat. While it does unpack my war, I still can't seem to get to it through a web browser...

Comment: What URL do you try to access?

Comment: @intargc check the logs (in /var/log/tomcat6/catalina.out I think).

Comment: Yep, I was about to say, I checked the logs and was getting some exceptions about java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission grails.env read).  I realized that in /etc/default/tomcat6 there is an option TOMCAT6_SECURITY. I set that to no, restarted tomcat and the application works.

Thanks!